# Samsung button click effect

Tags: android

While I was creating Calculator app same as installed in my S6 edge, I stuck when
design buttons. I want to make buttons look exactly same as calc app which comes in all samsung phones.I tried state button pressed but they have design like fading colors in and out for seconds which I ain't sure how to create.

Answer (score 0):

by simple way create new xml file called **clickable_button.xml**
inside it write this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_clicked" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button"/>
</selector>
```

don't for get to make two drawable files one seem clicked and another not clicked

finally set your button background with clickable_button ;)